# How to read the technical specs for the iPhone 3G correctly

Tags: iphone

I saw people wrote these technical specifications in iPhone 3G (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_3G)

```
Quad-band GSM/GPRS/EDGE
(850 900 1,800 1,900 MHz)
Tri-band UMTS/HSDPA 3.6
(850 1,900 2,100 MHz)
```

So how to read the above technical specification correctly (ie to clarify these info so that the customers can understand)?

Comment: If you continue to read that article it is all explained in it.

Answer (score 1):

4 channels of AM radio

> Quad-band GSM/GPRS/EDGE
>   (850 900 1,800 1,900 MHz)

3 channels of FM radio

> Tri-band UMTS/HSDPA 3.6
>   (850 1,900 2,100 MHz)

Except that GSM+ and UMTS+ are a little more complicated than the old radio standards, but what you really need to explain to customers is what carrier they select means that not all of these channels and flavors of radio encodings will be active at any one time.

The capital letters are at the most basic, just different speeds of transfer on the same frequency channel so you might just gloss that over until the carrier coverage is compared to make sure that high or medium speed data will be provided.

Comment: but how to read "GSM/GPRS/EDGE" ? do we need to say either GSM or GPRS or EDGE standard?

Comment: @tim I'd explain those as different gears on the same frequency. Your question was exceptionally vague as to what you didn't get and I wouldn't expect many consumers to even care about different speed since they can usually just look at signal strength bars to know why the phone is slow or dropping calls.

Comment: I mean should i say like this "supporting 3 standards: GSM, GPRS and EDGE; and supporting 4 radio frequency bands: 850 MHz, 900 MHz, 1800 MHz and 1900 MHz"

Comment: Depending upon customer, you can simplify and say, the phone function works in US, Europe and Asia (including Japan), rather then spelling frequency numbers.- Quad Band

Comment: the customer need to know the correct Band number so that they can compare with what their carrier provides

Comment: the quad band phone will work anywhere in the world with any carrier the Frequencies are industry standards. there is no 945, 1623, or 1957....

Comment: about Tri-Band? is it for 3G

Answer (score 0):

I think we should say like this:

> Quad-band GSM 2G cellular connectivity with GPRS and EDGE support for
>   higher data transfer;
>
> Tri-band UMTS 3G Data cellular connectivity with HSDPA 3.6 for
>   enhanced 3G (Wikipedia)

Not sure if this is the right way, but that is all info i found in Wiki.